# ubuntu 20.04 blank screen after suspend and/or closing laptop lid and reopening and/or logging in

Tags: 20.04, gnome, suspend, laptop

First of all, don't consider this a duplicate question since none of the existing solutions work for me plus I dont see anyone.

Issue : laptop screen remains black after suspending and/or closing laptop lid and reopening and/or logging in. Though I can't accurately reproduce the issue, I can gurantee that this issue occurs after suspending and waking more than 2 times. Laptop fans and backlit keyboard wakes up: so its only the display which is affected.

Additional info : system has an Ubuntu-Windows10 dual boot with both grub and uefi bios running peacefully without pissing of each other.

``````
system info:
                          ./+o+-       karthik@knair
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.8.0-50-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 27m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2002
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.0.17
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1920x1080
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 3.36.5
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: Mutter
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Adwaita
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Yaru
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Ubuntu 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      Disk: 13G / 87G (16%)
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics @ 6x 2.375GHz
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     GPU: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.38.0, 5.8.0-50-generic, LLVM 11.0.0)
                   ````` +oo+++o\:     RAM: 2508MiB / 7439MiB
                          `oo++.
``````

NOTE:

1. The kernel is already the latest : so it's not that conventional amd issues with kernel 5.4 and/or 4.x.
2. NONE of the existing solns stating ctrl+alt+{any function key} lit up the screen : so please dont suggest the same.
3. Installing xscreensaver reduced the issue frequency, but didn't eliminate it completely.

**Please someone help ASAP : I'm really stressed about this**

Comment: Not really enough information to go on. I presume you have to hard power off and reboot to be able to use the laptop again? Can you go back in the syslog and look in the logs around the time it tries to wake up. Then edit your question and add these.

Comment: Please read this article & see if applies to you. I was able to fix the no-suspend lid close issue on Thinkbook 14 AMD completely & explicitly set HandleLidSwitch=suspend & it still works. https://lucraymond.net/2021/07/09/fixing-suspend-resume-on-lenovo-thinkbook-15-g2-are-laptop-with-amd-in-linux/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a workaround

1. Set "blank screen" to "never" in settings>power
2. Set "automatic suspend" to "off" in settings>power
3. Set "power button action" to anything other than "suspend" in settings>power
4. The most important :
   Open logind.conf file in
   etc/systemd using gedit

> sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf

Then uncomment (remove the #) the line containing "HandleLidSwitch" and set its value to "ignore"

Answer (score 0):

-Using another ubuntu version
-Changing graphics card driver, "nvidia driver 515 tested" worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).