# Black screen when waking up from suspend in ubuntu 20.04/22.04/21.10 with Iris Xe graphics

Tags: 20.04, kernel, suspend, 21.04, 21.10

I am having problems with my laptop not waking up properly from suspend.

I originally installed ubuntu 20.04 on my fujitsu U9311x with Intel Iris Xe Graphics. Now I have updated to 21.10 but the problem persists. It goes into suspend fine but when I resume I get a black screen. The computer actually resumes fine (if I have an external monitor hooked up as a second display it shows the login screen) so it must be some graphics problem, possibly related to the Iris Xe graphics card.

I am running kernel 5.11.0-44-generic (started out with 55.11.40-generic). I also tried linux-oem-20.04 and linux-oem-20.04c, but did not fix the suspend problem and broke the touchpad.

I have tried to change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT from "quiet splash" to "quiet acpi_osi=Linux nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor splash" and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX from "" to "nouveau.blacklist=1" and "nouveau.modeset=0" without any luck.

My bios is pretty recent (version 2.21 from July 2021). I have been trying to update the bios to the latest version (2.23), but have run into some problems. I get a boot failure if I try to boot with a FreeDOS iso usb stick. I can get the laptop to boot with a WinPE iso usb stick, but if I then execute the bios in WinPE it does not flash it (I just get the prompt back). So still working on that. But I am not totally convinced that the bios is the problem.

I found this post:

[Black Screen after wake from suspend on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367188/black-screen-after-wake-from-suspend-on-ubuntu-21-04)

where it seems the person got the wake up to work with kernel version 5.4.100 for instance. I tried to install it but get kernel panic (I had to sign the kernel myself for secure boot so maybe something went wrong).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks and cheers,

Sara

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, can you set the BIOS secure boot OFF. UEFI + secure boot is no luck to any linux distro.